# Argmax of a multidimensional array along a subset of dimensions in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, max, argmax

Say, Y is a 7-dimensional array, and I need an efficient way to maximize it along the last 3 dimensions, that will work on GPU.
As a result I need a 4-dimensional array with maximal values of Y and three 4-dimensional arrays with the indices of these values in the last three dimensions.
I can do

```
[Y7, X7] = max(Y , [], 7);
[Y6, X6] = max(Y7, [], 6);
[Y5, X5] = max(Y6, [], 5);
```

Then I have already found the values (Y5) and the indices along the 5th dimension (X5). But I still need indices along the 6th and 7th dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Let `N` denote the number of dimensions along which to maximize.

1. Reshape `Y` to collapse the last `N` dimensions into one.
2. Maximize along the collapsed dimensions. This gives argmax as a linear index over those dimensions.
3. Unroll the linear index into `N` subindices, one for each dimension.

The following code works **for any number of dimensions** (not necessarily `7` and `3` as in your example). To achieve that, it handles the size of `Y` generically and uses a comma-separated list obtained from a cell array to get `N` outputs from `sub2ind`.

```
Y = rand(2,3,2,3,2,3,2); % example 7-dimensional array
N = 3; % last dimensions along which to maximize
D = ndims(Y);
sz = size(Y);
[~, ind] = max(reshape(Y, [sz(1:D-N) prod(sz(D-N+1:end))]), [], D-N+1);
sub = cell(1,N);
[sub{:}] = ind2sub(sz(D-N+1:D), ind);
```

As a **check**, after running the above code, observe for example `Y(2,3,1,2,:)` (shown as a row vector for convenience):

```
>> reshape(Y(2,3,1,2,:), 1, [])
ans =
    0.5621    0.4352    0.3672    0.9011    0.0332    0.5044    0.3416    0.6996    0.0610    0.2638    0.5586    0.3766
```

The maximum is seen to be `0.9011`, which occurs at the `4`th position (where "position" is defined along the `N=3` collapsed dimensions). In fact,

```
>> ind(2,3,1,2)
ans =
     4
>> Y(2,3,1,2,ind(2,3,1,2))
ans =
    0.9011
```

or, in terms of the `N=3` subindices,

```
>> Y(2,3,1,2,sub{1}(2,3,1,2),sub{2}(2,3,1,2),sub{3}(2,3,1,2))
ans =
    0.9011
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, this works perfectly even on GPU and is very fast!